# "Rounded out" footer button effect

Tags: css, css-position

In the mobile webapp I am currently working on I would like to create a footer similar to the one shown in the image below

While I could use a raster of SVG image to accomplish this I have set out to do so using pure CSS3.  My current effort is shown below

```js
function eventify()
{
 let svgs = document.getElementById('ftr').getElementsByTagName('svg');

 for(let i=0,count = svgs.length;i < count;i++)
 {
  svgs[i].addEventListener('mousedown',activateItem,{passive:true});
 }
}

function activateItem(e)
{
 let tgt = e.currentTarget;
 if (tgt.classList.contains('raised')) return;

 let raiseds = document.getElementsByClassName('raised');
 for(let i=0,count = raiseds.length;i < count;i++) raiseds[i].classList.remove('raised');

 
 let tbCL = document.getElementById('thumbBox').classList;
 while (0 < tbCL.length) tbCL.remove(tbCL.item(0));

 tbCL.add(tgt.classList.item(0));
 tgt.classList.add('raised');
}

eventify();
```

```css
body,html
{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 font-family:arial;
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
}

footer
{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:calc(100vh - 40px);
 background-color:lime;
}

footer > svg
{
 pointer-events:all;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#thumbBox
{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:60%;
 top:-60%;
}

#thumb
{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 border-radius:100%;
 background-color:lime;
}

#thumbCurves
{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
}

#thumbCurves::before
{
 position:absolute;
 right:95%;
 left:-30%;
 bottom:40%;
 top:30%;
 background-color:lime;
 z-index:100;
 content:' ';
}

#thumbCurves::after
{
 position:absolute;
 left:95%;
 right:-30%;
 bottom:40%;
 top:30%;
 background-color:lime;
 z-index:100;
 content:' ';
}

#thumbCurves > div:first-of-type
{
 position:absolute;
 right:96%;
 left:-60%;
 bottom:40%;
 top:0%;
 background-color:black;
 border-radius:100%;
 z-index:200; 
}

#thumbCurves > div:last-of-type
{
 position:absolute;
 left:96%;
 right:-60%;
 bottom:40%;
 top:0%;
 background-color:black;
 border-radius:100%;
 z-index:200; 
}

.home
{
 left:17.5%;
 right:calc(100vw - 22.5%);
}

.search
{
 left:47.5%;
 right:calc(100vw - 52.5%);
}

.map
{
 left:82.5%;
 right:calc(100vw - 87.5%);
}

#home,#map,#search
{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:10%;
 top:0;
 transform:scale(0.6);
}

#home > circle,#map > circle,#search > circle
{
 visibility:hidden;
}

.raised
{
 bottom:60% !important;
 top:-60% !important;
 transform:scale(0.9) !important;
}

.raised#home > circle,.raised#map > circle,.raised#search > circle
{
 visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<footer id='ftr'>
    <div id='thumbBox' class='home'>
     <div id='thumb'>
      <div id='thumbCurves'>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> 
    
    <svg id='home' class='home raised' viewBox="0 0 509 509" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2"><circle cx="254.031" cy="254.031" r="254.031" style="fill:#fff"/><path d="M391.554 306.684a7.092 7.092 0 0 0-4.979-2.064c-1.853 0-3.67.753-4.98 2.064a7.087 7.087 0 0 0-2.064 4.98c0 1.852.753 3.669 2.064 4.979a7.097 7.097 0 0 0 4.98 2.064 7.092 7.092 0 0 0 4.979-2.064 7.092 7.092 0 0 0 2.064-4.979c0-1.853-.753-3.67-2.064-4.98Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero"/><path d="M424.61 401.821h-30.992v-65.505a7.045 7.045 0 0 0-7.043-7.044 7.045 7.045 0 0 0-7.044 7.044v65.505H156.957v-66.209a7.044 7.044 0 0 0-14.087 0v66.209h-19.722V216.578L251.34 116.499l128.191 100.079v66.912a7.044 7.044 0 0 0 14.087 0v-55.914l1.232.961a7.023 7.023 0 0 0 4.331 1.492 7.033 7.033 0 0 0 4.983-2.063l25.405-25.406a7.049 7.049 0 0 0 2.063-4.981 7.049 7.049 0 0 0-2.71-5.552l-42.347-33.061V88.385a7.044 7.044 0 0 0-7.044-7.044h-40.822a7.044 7.044 0 0 0-7.044 7.044v27.713l-75.992-59.326a7.061 7.061 0 0 0-8.668 0L73.756 192.027a7.049 7.049 0 0 0-2.71 5.552c0 1.868.743 3.66 2.063 4.981l25.406 25.406c2.503 2.502 6.524 2.749 9.315.571l1.231-.961v174.245H78.069a7.044 7.044 0 0 0 0 14.087H424.61a7.044 7.044 0 0 0 0-14.087ZM345.752 95.428h26.736v52.54l-26.736-20.872V95.428ZM104.071 213.6l-15.369-15.37L251.34 71.259 413.977 198.23l-15.369 15.37-142.935-111.589a7.03 7.03 0 0 0-4.333-1.492 7.031 7.031 0 0 0-4.334 1.492L104.071 213.6Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero"/><path d="M318.957 208.829H183.722a7.044 7.044 0 0 0-7.044 7.043v135.235a7.044 7.044 0 0 0 7.044 7.044h135.235a7.044 7.044 0 0 0 7.044-7.044V215.872a7.044 7.044 0 0 0-7.044-7.043Zm-74.661 135.235h-53.531v-53.531h53.531v53.531Zm0-67.618h-53.531v-53.53h53.531v53.53Zm67.618 67.618h-53.531v-53.531h53.531v53.531Zm0-67.618h-53.531v-53.53h53.531v53.53Zm-162.001 24.305a7.043 7.043 0 0 0-7.043 7.043v.113a7.044 7.044 0 0 0 14.087 0v-.113a7.045 7.045 0 0 0-7.044-7.043Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero"/></svg>

    <svg id='search' class='search' viewBox="0 0 509 509" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2"><circle cx="254.031" cy="254.031" r="254.031" style="fill:#fff"/><path d="m406.139 353.56-71.194-71.199a124.492 124.492 0 0 0 19.117-66.447c0-69.108-56.024-125.125-125.13-125.125s-125.125 56.017-125.125 125.125c0 69.111 56.016 125.122 125.125 125.122a124.566 124.566 0 0 0 71.468-22.433l70.347 70.352a24.966 24.966 0 0 0 17.696 7.316 24.988 24.988 0 0 0 17.704-7.316c9.704-9.711 9.7-25.687-.008-35.395Zm-177.207-53.062c-46.71 0-84.579-37.867-84.579-84.579 0-46.711 37.869-84.581 84.579-84.581 46.712 0 84.578 37.87 84.578 84.581 0 46.712-37.866 84.579-84.578 84.579Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero"/></svg>

    <svg id='map' class='map' viewBox="0 0 509 509" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2"><circle cx="254.031" cy="254.031" r="254.031" style="fill:#fff"/><path d="M170.267 238.014h-15.45a10.162 10.162 0 0 0-9.316 6.13l-42.771 99.592 101.576-51.88c-12.159-16.825-24.19-35.382-34.039-53.842Zm196.515 6.13a10.16 10.16 0 0 0-9.313-6.13h-15.45c-18.6 34.854-45.697 70.873-62.934 90.689-12.123 13.905-33.777 13.889-45.881 0-1.238-1.422-7.702-8.906-16.605-20.413l-18.312 9.357 69.272 69.138 131.256-68.047-32.033-74.594ZM90.234 372.841l-5.525 12.866c-2.86 6.659 2.039 14.094 9.313 14.094h148.744c.93-.691.941-.649 5.935-3.238l-69.373-69.229-89.094 45.507Zm337.343 12.866-20.755-48.327-120.407 62.421h131.849c7.257 0 12.177-7.422 9.313-14.094Zm-161.301-239.37c0-5.578-4.547-10.112-10.133-10.112-5.589 0-10.133 4.534-10.133 10.112 0 5.575 4.544 10.112 10.133 10.112 5.585 0 10.133-4.537 10.133-10.112Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero"/><path d="M263.789 314.759c3.412-3.917 83.547-96.614 83.547-160.334 0-131.394-182.386-132.997-182.386 0 0 63.72 80.135 156.417 83.547 160.334 4.04 4.634 11.26 4.629 15.292 0Zm-38.045-168.422c0-16.728 13.637-30.336 30.399-30.336 16.759 0 30.396 13.608 30.396 30.336 0 16.726-13.637 30.333-30.396 30.333-16.762 0-30.399-13.607-30.399-30.333Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero"/></svg>
   </footer>
```

A few brief notes on my implementation

- I have placed the entire *thumb nail* effect in a `position:absolute` element which in turn has a `position:fixed` parent - the `footer` itself
- This makes it easy to shift the entire *thumb nail* left or right with a simple class re-assignment
- Within this I have an absolutely positioned circular `div` element to create the base rounding effect for the thumbnail
- Needless to say this on its own results in a sharp junction between the horizontal top of the footer and the thumbnail
- To get the *rounding out* effect I do two things

1. I position a square `div` element at the sharp junction
2. Above it (`z-order`) I place a circular `div` element with its background color set to the main background.  This has the effect of masking out the undesired portions of the square below it

This works.  However, there are a few issues that bother me

- The *rounded out* effect that I have achieved here is nice but not perfect. How can I improve it?
- I would like to add a cool transition effect when the footer buttons are clicked/tapped.  This would be along the lines of

1. The actual icons rising/sinking to their final positions gracefully rather than just popping into place
2. The *thumb nail* gracefully sliding to its new position

CSS transforms I assume will do that tricl but they have never quite been my speciality.  How can this be achieved?

Finally, I am counting on using % units in an absolutely positioned *thumb box* to ensure that the end result looks good on different mobile screens ranging from an ancient iPhone 5 right up to the latest greatest iPad.  I realize that this might require a media query or two which I have not shown here.  My last question - is it a reasonable assumption that `postion:absolute` on the * thumb box* as used here will deliver the responsivity I seek?

[image: A footer like this]

Comment: `transform: translateY(-36px);` and `transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;`

Comment: Technically, you can create any curve you want to arbitrary precision using this technique of combining circles see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1680058. However, seeing as you are already including `svg` tags, I think it is probably far easier (and maintainable) to draw the curve you want in svg and then position that along the top of your footer.